# Grails execute multiple native sql queries asynchronously

Tags: grails, asynchronous, grails-orm

I have a service that executes multiple native sql statements. Is it possible to run those sql statements asynchronously? My query looks something like this with multiple queries:

```
def sessionFactory
sessionFactory = ctx.sessionFactory  // this only necessary if your are working with the Grails console/shell
def session = sessionFactory.currentSession 

def query = session.createSQLQuery("select f.* from fee f where f.id = :filter)) order by f.name");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the new grails [Promises API](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.4.4/guide/async.html)

```
import static grails.async.Promises.*

List queriesToExecute = []

someList.each {
    //create task to execute query
    def t = task {
        //create and execute query here
      }

   queriesToExecute << t
}

def result = waitAll(queriesToExecute) //if you want to wait till queries are executed
//or if you dont want to wait, use this - onComplete(queriesToExecute) { List results -> }​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```